# Firebase authentication error auth/internal-error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

when using email/password authentication with firebase I am getting an error trying to log a user in

calling `.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`

it hits this endpoint `https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?` which returns a 400. The error contains:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "keyExpired",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
```

This has only started happening in the last day, but it is hard to tell from the HTTP response if this is an error on my end or google's. It return a 400 but then says internal error.

There are not meant to be any usage limits or key expirations for firebase so I am lost as to what is going on here

Comment: I think I have resolved the issue by specifying the key from the google developer console to setup firebase instead of the one firebase gives me in the UI. Still do not understand why this seems to have only just become an issue